# Where to find the configuration window for Clearcase plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, configuration, clearcase

I tried to following the instructions for CLearcase PlugIn for Jenkins.

```
 https://plugins.jenkins.io/clearcase-ucm-plugin
```

but I am confused about where is this "Main configuration screen for Clearcase UCM Plugin". Is it from clearcase UCM, or from the Jenkins I installed?

Answer (score 0):

The "Main configuration screen for Clearcase UCM Plugin." is the ClearCase elements you need to fill out in order for Jenkins to:

- have the right argument and
- make the right ClearCase commands and get the files for its workspace.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58001105/ccucm_config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1439193524000&api=v2]

Those fields are visible only because you have installed the "clearcase-ucm-plugin" for Jenkins.